# Creating arrow-headed background divs

Tags: html, css, svg

How can I create this with CSS:

[image: picture of my title and usbtitle]

I've tried using ::after and ::before, each with transform: skew(20deg) or skew -20deg, but it'll only work if the subtitle fits on one line, and there's no guarantee of that.

Having trouble, could really use a pointer or two. I'm trying to support IE9 and up, but more importantly the mobile OS's Android 4+ and iOS 7+

I'd be open to using SVG as well. I'm just less familiar with integrating it with HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could achieve this: http://jsbin.com/kotisisilu/2/edit?html,css,output

To do that I'm using :before and :after white elements that are rotated at the right of the element to cover the corners and make it look like an arrow.

The problem with this is that the covering elements must have the same color of the background.

It also can handle multiline, but you need to do some adjustements to handle more than two lines, you can adjust it with a maximum of lines in mind.

With css is hard to achieve this, would be interesting to use SVG instead and, in IE9, use a fallback with an Image or without the arrow.

**EDIT**

A SVG example: http://jsbin.com/viserozumo/2/edit?html,css,output

CSS:

```
div#arrow {
  position: relative;
  font-family: "Arial";
  background-color: #123456;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2em;
  padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}

div#arrow svg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: -30px;
}
```

And the HTML with SVG

```
  <div id="arrow">
    The awesome text<br>
    Multiline!
    <svg width="30px" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 10 10" preserveAspectRatio="none">
      <polygon fill=#123456 stroke-width=0 points="0,0 10,5 0,10" />
    </svg>
  </div>
```

Comment: this breaks when it moves onto the next line, also could cover up outside elements (unless you put a overflow:hidden;) on the container.

Comment: I know, its problematic, I would use SVG for this, because looks like a simple problem, but solving it with CSS needs some ugly tricks

Comment: Yeah, plus SVG seems like it'll have great support within a year.

Comment: How would you do it with SVG?

Comment: Exactly, there's a really nice talk about this by Sara Soueidan, must see:  http://slides.com/sarasoueidan/building-better-interfaces-with-svg

Comment: @Costa I dont know much SVG yet (bad for me) but this is a way to make it, but static http://jsbin.com/feyuvapivi/1/edit?html,output

Comment: @Costa Check out this: http://jsbin.com/valexijoqu/1/edit?html,css,output I think it fixes the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can actually draw a triangle by using borders and than position it outside of content div.

```
.arrow {
    background : gray;
    width : 250px;
    height : 50px;
    position : relative;
}

.arrow:after {
    content : '';
    display : block;
    position : absolute;
    right: -20px;
    top : 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;

    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 25px 0 25px 20px;
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #007bff;
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/823n08k7/1/)

Comment: Change the border-color to gray as well.

Comment: Thanks for the help. My arrow needs to be responsive. It can't have a fixed height.